# High Availability clustering for mesos

Tags: azure, mesosphere, dcos

When using DC/OS on Azure, and I deploy a container, how can I guarantee if I launch 2 instances that they are on different physical machines (provided I have at least 2 agents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not Azure specific, it applies to any DC/OS (and with it Marathon) setup: you use constraints for placement, in this case `UNIQUE` for `hostname`, see also the [Marathon docs](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/constraints.html) for details.